# Browser redirects signin through HTTP even though the page has been served through HTTPS

Tags: azure, https, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I have a .NET Core 2 web app deployed in Azure web app service. I am using the Microsoft provided `application.azurewebsites.net` domain and their SSL certificate.

Authentication is set up to use Azure Active Directory, and I have configured all the settings (Reply URLs, application home page, etc.) in the corresponding app registration.

Everything works fine when I run the application with the HTTPS Only setting set to off in the blade Custom domains -> Custom Hostnames -> HTTPS only.

[image: Custom domains blade]

However, if I set HTTPS only to on, the authentication stops working, after the following set of requests:

[image: http requests]

As you can see the last request fails with an HTTP 500 error, whose stack trace is the following:

```
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
       Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://application.azurewebsites.net/account/signin
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[14]
  .AspNetCore.Correlation. state property not found.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler[4]
  Error from RemoteAuthentication: Correlation failed..
fail: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.ExceptionHandlerMiddleware[0]
  An unhandled exception has occurred: Correlation failed.
System.Exception: Correlation failed.
```

Looking in the Internet and on SO for this 'correlation failed' error has been of no help.

I think that the cause of the error must be related to POST request not being made using HTTPS, it is done with raw HTTP (the lock icon is broken) but I do not know how to fix my application to force the browser to perform that request using HTTPS. In my application all URLs are relative.

Is my assessment correct? Any idea on how to fix this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

**Additional information**:
The first request URL, the one returning 200 status code, has the parameter `redirect_uri` set to `http://application.azurewebsites.net/account/signin`. I understand the redirect uri is set by .NET Core framework, but where can I force it to be https?.

**OAuth client configuration**
In `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddAuthentication(sharedOptions =>
                {
                    sharedOptions.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    sharedOptions.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                    .AddAzureAd(options => ConfigurationManager.Current.Bind("AzureAd", options))
                    .AddCookie(options =>
                    {
                        if (Localization.CurrentLanguage == null)
                        {
                            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/" + Localization.DefaultLanguage + "/error/403";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            options.AccessDeniedPath = "/" + Localization.CurrentLanguage + "/error/403";
                        }
                    });
```

Method `AddAzureAd`:

```
public static AuthenticationBuilder AddAzureAd(this AuthenticationBuilder builder, Action<AzureAdOptions> configureOptions)
        {
            builder.Services.Configure(configureOptions);
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfigureOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>, ConfigureAzureOptions>();
            builder.AddOpenIdConnect();
            return builder;
        }

        private class ConfigureAzureOptions : IConfigureNamedOptions<OpenIdConnectOptions>
        {
            private readonly AzureAdOptions _azureOptions;

            public ConfigureAzureOptions(IOptions<AzureAdOptions> azureOptions)
            {
                _azureOptions = azureOptions.Value;
            }

            public void Configure(string name, OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                options.ClientId = _azureOptions.ClientId;
                options.Authority = $"{_azureOptions.Instance}{_azureOptions.TenantId}";
                options.UseTokenLifetime = true;
                options.CallbackPath = _azureOptions.CallbackPath;
                options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            }

            public void Configure(OpenIdConnectOptions options)
            {
                Configure(Options.DefaultName, options);
            }
        }
```

Azure active directory configuration in `appsettings.json`:

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "myazuread.onmicrosoft.com",
    "TenantId": "3b9e0e3a-1e14-4026-8616-2f6febd8ec52",
    "ClientId": "d40127e7-1f1c-49b7-8fec-2c5e4757d004",
    "CallbackPath": "/account/signin"
  }
```

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the client's configuration. Can you add that to your question?

Comment: I've added more details on that. As you can see, the callback path is relative not absolute. I do not understand why the redirection is made through raw HTTP. In addition, I've checked that if I copy and paste the request to `login.microsoftonline.com` in the browser, manually modifying the `redirect_uri` to use HTTPS everything works fine. If you need any other detail feel free to ask it.

Comment: I've had many ASP.NET Core apps in App Service using AAD auth and haven't seen this problem before. Have you surely registered the HTTPS variant of the reply URL in AAD?

Comment: Yes, I've checked the reply URLs many times before. In addition, the error you get when the repy URL is wrong or not there is a different one.

Comment: @joanlofe, did you ever managed to fix this? I'm facing the same problem. I've managed to manually hack an https instead of an http and it works, but I can't implement that. Thanks.